# Convergence time is changing dramatically when running a script multiple times

Tags: python, time, heuristics, convergence

I have a `script.py`, with 3 algorithms. I want to count the convergence time of each one. 
Here is exactly what I do for example on `algo1`:

```
start=time.time()

call_function1

call_function2

....

end=time.time()

convergence_time=end-start.
```

1. I don't know if it's `time()` that should be used for such objective or there is another builtin function?

   I use a `script.sh` that runs the following command:

   ```
   for x in {1,.1000}; do python3 script.py &done
   ```

   The objective is to run the `script.py` many times.
2. When running that script multiple times, the convergence_time varies dramatically. For instance, if I run it only once, the time would be `0.0034`. But when it runs multiple times it can reach `14.86` on each algorithm!! Would anyone help me understand what is going on? I don't really run anything else on the server.

Comment: Running each of the 1000 instances of `script.py` in parallel invokes a great deal of overhead (unless you have 1000 cores) that is affecting your timing. Instead, run the 1000 jobs *serially*, then divide the total running time by 1000 for a more accurate average running time.

Comment: Use the `timeit` module instead of `time.time()` and a manual shell loop.

Comment: In fact, i will need to have the average convergence time of each algorithm seperately, but i can't seperate the three algorithms on different script. Otherwise, how can i run them serially, i thought that for loop run it in serial mode!

Comment: `for i in {1..1000}; do python3 script.py; done` would do it serially; you are using `&` which causes each instance to run asynchronously in the background.

Comment: Ah okay, now it's good. Thank you!